# Android: Markers is added to mapbox with super delay

Tags: android, mapbox-android

I am using map box in my android application. After initializing map box I want to add marker when on longClick on map box so in order according official site I added markerview dependency to application gradle:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-markerview-v7:0.2.0'
}
```

And then I implements `MapboxMap.OnMapLongClickListener` and override `onMapLongClick`.

When mapview is ready I enable `enableLocationComponent` and create `markerViewManager` and set map `long click listener`.

```
 mapView.getMapAsync(mapboxMap -> {
            this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
            mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS, style -> {
                createCustomAnimationView();
                moveTo(home_longitude, home_latitude, home_zoom);
                enableLocationComponent();
                markerViewManager = new MarkerViewManager(mapView, mapboxMap);
                mapboxMap.addOnMapLongClickListener(this);
                createCustomAnimationView();
            });
        });
```

Finally in `onMapLongClick` overrided method I make a imageview and add to markerViewManager.

```
@Override
public boolean onMapLongClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(requireContext());
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            (int) Measurement.convertDpToPixel(32, requireContext()),
            (int) Measurement.convertDpToPixel(32, requireContext())));
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.location_ic);
    MarkerView markerView = new MarkerView(new LatLng(point.getLatitude(), point.getLongitude()), imageView);
    markerViewManager.addMarker(markerView);
    return false;
}
```

When I run application and do long click on screen:

> First problem: *location_ic* appear on the top and left of the screen and after a second or more, icon placed in right place
>
> Other problem:
> When I move map, those markers stay fixed and not moved with map but after a second or more then placed in right place.

I hope I had explained clearly but if you are not understanding I uploaded a small video !!!
[My video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B66WYC1WBNbPWnJUQVBVcGRCSTVIUE9hVXdfRzB5RnB6NllF/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Looks like the video no long is available, states the file is in thrash can ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after a few days and googleing, I finally decided to use `SymbolManager` to add marker on mapbox:

just add :

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v7:0.5.0'
}
```

to app gradle and then Initialize the plugin on `onMapReady` like below:

```
symbolManager = new SymbolManager(mapView, mapboxMap,style);
symbolManager.setIconAllowOverlap(true);
symbolManager.setTextAllowOverlap(true);
```

and use :

```
symbolManager.create(new SymbolOptions()
                .withLatLng(point)
                .withIconImage(IMAGE_MARKER_DEFAULT));
```

for helping look [this page](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/master/plugin-annotation/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/annotation/SymbolManager.java) and [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/annotation/#install-the-annotation-plugin).

I hope it can be helpful.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to add/remove markers with symbolmanager during runtime https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57991180/how-to-add-remove-markers-with-mapbox-android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working with markers in mapbox too. But they are referred as "Symbols" in the latest versions.

To use them add the mapbox android sdk dependency to your project (tutorial from mapbox [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/first-steps-android-sdk/) ) and follow the other tutorial to use the symbol layer ( link [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/marker-symbol-layer/) ).

If you have all your markers as a GeoJSON file, you can also add to a custom map that you would style on the mapbox website and then use in your app. ( other informations [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/markers/) )

I hope this can help you, this is my first attempt to answer at someone.

Comment: I think symbols use for bulk marker. I want to just add a few marker with point on map. But i wondered that what is my problem and why i get this problems :-( @PottokDev