# How to add/remove markers with MAPBOX android SDK

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am adding markers using the recommend way by [adding the marker to the map style as a new layer](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/first-steps-android-sdk/#add-markers)

```js
    List<Feature> symbolLayerIconFeatureList .....

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

        symbolLayerIconFeatureList = new ArrayList<>();
        symbolLayerIconFeatureList.add(Feature.fromGeometry(
                Point.fromLngLat(-57.225365, -33.213144)));
        symbolLayerIconFeatureList.add(Feature.fromGeometry(
                Point.fromLngLat(-54.14164, -33.981818)));
        symbolLayerIconFeatureList.add(Feature.fromGeometry(
                Point.fromLngLat(-56.990533, -30.583266)));

        mapboxMap.setStyle(new Style.Builder().fromUri("mapbox://styles/mapbox/cjf4m44iw0uza2spb3q0a7s41")

        // Add the SymbolLayer icon image to the map style
                .withImage(ICON_ID, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        MainActivity.this.getResources(), R.drawable.red_marker))

        // Adding a GeoJson source for the SymbolLayer icons.
                .withSource(new GeoJsonSource(SOURCE_ID,
                        FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(symbolLayerIconFeatureList)))

        // Adding the actual SymbolLayer to the map style. An offset is added that the bottom of the red
        // marker icon gets fixed to the coordinate, rather than the middle of the icon being fixed to
        // the coordinate point. This is offset is not always needed and is dependent on the image
        // that you use for the SymbolLayer icon.
                .withLayer(new SymbolLayer(LAYER_ID, SOURCE_ID)
                        .withProperties(PropertyFactory.iconImage(ICON_ID),
                                iconAllowOverlap(true),
                                iconOffset(new Float[]{0f, -9f}))
                ), new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
            @Override
            public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {

        // Map is set up and the style has loaded. Now you can add additional data or make other map adjustments.


            }
        });
    }
```

I would like to add or remove one of the markers at will during runtime, let's assume this comes after an api call.
I have tried this:

```
 markerCoordinates.remove(Feature.fromGeometry(
                        Point.fromLngLat(-57.225365, -33.213144)));
 mapView.invalidate();
```

But it does not work.
Other options suggested i remove the layer but it hasn't worked.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with a few steps:

1. Get the layer source with `GeoJsonSource source = mapboxMap.getSourceAs(SOURCE_ID);`
2. Update your list of features `symbolLayerIconFeatureList` by adding or removing any feature you want.
3. Give your `source` the new feature list `source.setGeoJson(FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(symbolLayerIconFeatureList));`

And you are good to go.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Fixed my issue. But will it be able to handle several coordinates?

Comment: In your list `symbolLayerIconFeatureList` you can add any number of coordinates, the layer system of _Mapbox_ can handle large amount of data. Or did I just not understand your question?

Answer (score 0):

you can remove marker by sourceId. for ex :- `mapStyle.removeSource(sourceId)`

Comment: I have tried this `new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {  style.removeSource("marker-source");}, 10000 );` but my marker is still visible on the map.

Comment: I quit and changed to google maps. Mapbox didn't seem to handle this well.